# What is the logic behind game coding, moving graphics simultaneously?

Tags: c#

I was reviewing a code from a simple PONG game code in c#, the logic as far as I could understand was reading a key press (UP and Down) in a infinte loop and update the position of the ball and bar each n milliseconds one after another.

I want to know how to draw objects on a graphic box simultaneously?

I am just interested in making simple games using a imagebox and simple graohics.

Comment: Which framework do you want to use (XNA, Silverlight, WPF, WinForms, Mono, ...) and what have you tried so far? If this is a simple "code this for me" question, you should better ask at [the programmers site](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I am just interested in making simple games using a imagebox and simple graohics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make really simple games like Tetris or other puzzle-like, you could simply drop the "infinite loop" part. I've seen plenty of simple games built with Winforms/user controls/standard events (keypress/mousemove...).

If you plan to write something more complicated, then you probably want start learning [XNA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb203894%28XNAGameStudio.40%29.aspx). Microsoft kindly provides useful [starter kits](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/).

Answer (score 0):

You don't do it simultaneously, you do it in a loop but that loop happens so fast that a human cannot tell they are being updated one at a time.

Comment: well, you don't invalidate the screen after each update. you update them all and then draw everything. so I would say that the are all updated at the same time. Perhaps depending how you interpret "update" :)